# Lua - Display field ASCII Dissector

Tags: filter, lua, wireshark-dissector, protofield

I am currently working on my first ever Protocol Dissector. I am facing a problem that I can't solve. Basically I have a field which is 8 bytes long (but is defined over 9 bytes), so I created a bitfield to define this protofield.

Here are the deffinitions of the field I have tested so far:

```
a) local harer_id = ProtoField.string   ("myProto.harer_id","Harer ID", base.ASCII)
b) local harer_id =  ProtoField.uint64   ("myProto.harer_id", "Harer ID", base.HEX )
```

Then I add it to the dissection Tree on the following way:

```
  local harer_id_long = tvbuf:range(16,9)
  body:add(harer_id, harer_id_long:bitfield(4,64))
```

Which ends up giving the following errors:

```
a) Gives no error but it doesnt return the value on ASCII format
    What I get: 0x0000000000313030
    What I want: 0x0000000000313030 (100)
b) calling 'add' on bad self (string expected, got userdata)
```

If any of you have any suggestions I would appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance,

Martin

EDIT 1:

I wrote this code which will get the ASCII table values from each byte on the field's value:

I don't know how to make it work so that it displays the ASCII value on the packet view.

```
 function getASCII (str)
    resultStr = ""
    asciiValue="" 
    for i = 3, string.len(tostring(str))-1, 2 do
        asciiValue = string.char(tonumber(tostring(string.sub(tostring(str),i,i+1)), 16))
        if asciiValue~=nil then 
            resultStr = resultStr .. tostring(tonumber(asciiValue))
        end
    end
    resultStr = string.gsub(resultStr, "nil", "") 
    return resultStr
 end
```

Comment: where do body and harer come from? and where do you use harer_id? please provide all related information.

Comment: The deffinition of harer_id is on the code I shared. Then, body is a subtree from the dissection tree where I am adding the harer_id field      


      `local tree   = root:add(udpProto, tvbuf:range(0,pktlen))
      local header = tree:add(header, tvbuf:range(0,HDR_LEN))
      local body   = tree:add(body, tvbuf:range(9,BODY_LEN))`


The issue here is how can I define the field so that when it is displayed on the packet details zone, the ASCII value will also be displayed

Comment: *"I have a field which is 8 bytes long (but is defined over 9 bytes)"* - What??

Comment: Yeah... That is what is making things complicated.. The first 4 bits and the last 4 bits of those 9 bytes are from the field before and after the one I want. The mask would be like 0x0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternate method that also works for me.  I'm not sure which you prefer, but you now have 2 to choose from (assuming you can get my original method to work):

```
local harer_id = ProtoField.uint64("myProto.harer_id", "Harer ID", base.HEX)

harer_item = body:add(harer_id, tvbuf(16, 9):bitfield(4, 64))
harer_item:set_len(9)

vals = {}
for i = 0, 7 do
    vals[i] = bit.bor(buf(16 + i, 2):bitfield(4, 8), 0x30)
end
harer_item:append_text(" (" ..
    tonumber(string.format("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c", vals[0], vals[1], vals[2], vals[3], vals[4], vals[5], vals[6], vals[7])) ..
    ")")
```

---

**EDIT**: Here is a simple Lua dissector and sample packet you can use to test this solution:

```
-- Protocol
local p_foo = Proto("foo", "FOO Protocol")

-- Fields
local f_foo_res1 = ProtoField.uint8("foo.res1", "Reserved 1", base.DEC, nil, 0xf0)
local f_foo_str = ProtoField.uint64("foo.str", "String", base.HEX)
local f_foo_res2 = ProtoField.uint8("foo.res2", "Reserved 2 ", base.DEC, nil, 0x0f)
local f_foo_res3 = ProtoField.uint8("foo.res3", "Reserved 3", base.HEX)
local f_foo_ipv6 = ProtoField.ipv6("foo.ipv6", "IPv6 Address")

p_foo.fields = { f_foo_res1, f_foo_str, f_foo_res2, f_foo_res3, f_foo_ipv6 }

-- Dissection
function p_foo.dissector(buf, pinfo, tree)
    local foo_tree = tree:add(p_foo, buf(0,-1))

    pinfo.cols.protocol:set("FOO")
    foo_tree:add(f_foo_res1, buf(0, 1))

    str_item = foo_tree:add(f_foo_str, buf(0, 9):bitfield(4, 64))
    str_item:set_len(9)

    vals = {}
    for i = 0, 7 do
        vals[i] = bit.bor(buf(i, 2):bitfield(4, 8), 0x30)
    end
    str_item:append_text(" (" ..
        tonumber(string.format("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c", vals[0], vals[1], vals[2], vals[3], vals[4], vals[5], vals[6], vals[7])) ..
        ")")

    foo_tree:add(f_foo_res2, buf(9, 1))
    foo_tree:add(f_foo_res3, buf(10, 1))
    foo_tree:add(f_foo_ipv6, buf(11, 16))
end

-- Registration
local udp_table = DissectorTable.get("udp.port")
udp_table:add(33333, p_foo)
```

Use [`text2pcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/text2pcap.html) to convert this data into a packet that Wireshark can read or use Wireshark's *"File -> Import From Hex Dump..."* feature:

```
0000  00 0e b6 00 00 02 00 0e b6 00 00 01 08 00 45 00
0010  00 37 00 00 40 00 40 11 b5 ea c0 00 02 65 c0 00
0020  02 66 82 35 82 35 00 23 00 00 03 03 13 23 33 43
0030  53 63 70 80 64 20 01 0d b8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0040  00 00 00 00 01
```

My Wireshark details:
Compiled (64-bit) with Qt 5.6.2, with WinPcap (4_1_3), with GLib 2.42.0, with
zlib 1.2.8, with SMI 0.4.8, with c-ares 1.12.0, with Lua 5.2.4, with GnuTLS
3.4.11, with Gcrypt 1.7.6, with MIT Kerberos, with GeoIP, with nghttp2 1.14.0,
with LZ4, with Snappy, with libxml2 2.9.4, with QtMultimedia, with AirPcap, with
SBC, with SpanDSP.

Comment: I really like the solutions that you are suggesting, but they seem to not be working for me. What can I be doing wrong? "Lua Error.... : attempt to concatenate a nil value"

Comment: I amended my answer with more details.  You should be able to use the Lua script I provided and test it against the packet I also provided.

Comment: Thank you very much,man! Really appreciate you effort! I've managed to make your example work, which is great. And I feel like I know what is happening with my code. The problem is that in my code most of the fields are 00, so when is converted to ASCII, it tries to concatenate a nil value and breaks.

Comment: I managed to solve that problem, I will edit your answer to make it even more complete, have a look if you want. But, anyway, many thanks! You have saved me so much time and suggested very nice posible solutions. :)

Comment: Your edit was OK, but I modified my solution by unconditionally OR'ing 0x30 to the value.  If it's already an ASCII digit 0x30-0x39, it won't matter, but if it's a binary 0x00, then they will be converted to ASCII 0x30.  This just avoids having to check if it's less than 0x30 or not.  Use whichever method you like better though.

Comment: clean. I like that!

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more efficient way to do this, but you could try something like this?

```
harer_id = ProtoField.string("myProto.harer_id", "Harer ID", base.ASCII)

harer_item = body:add(harer_id, tvbuf(16, 9))
harer_item:set_text("Harer ID: " ..
    tonumber(
        string.char(bit.bor(bit.band(bit.lshift(tvbuf(16, 1):uint(), 4), 0xf0), bit.rshift(tvbuf(17, 1):uint(), 4))) ..
        string.char(bit.bor(bit.band(bit.lshift(tvbuf(17, 1):uint(), 4), 0xf0), bit.rshift(tvbuf(18, 1):uint(), 4))) ..
        string.char(bit.bor(bit.band(bit.lshift(tvbuf(18, 1):uint(), 4), 0xf0), bit.rshift(tvbuf(19, 1):uint(), 4))) ..
        string.char(bit.bor(bit.band(bit.lshift(tvbuf(19, 1):uint(), 4), 0xf0), bit.rshift(tvbuf(20, 1):uint(), 4))) ..
        string.char(bit.bor(bit.band(bit.lshift(tvbuf(20, 1):uint(), 4), 0xf0), bit.rshift(tvbuf(21, 1):uint(), 4))) ..
        string.char(bit.bor(bit.band(bit.lshift(tvbuf(21, 1):uint(), 4), 0xf0), bit.rshift(tvbuf(22, 1):uint(), 4))) ..
        string.char(bit.bor(bit.band(bit.lshift(tvbuf(22, 1):uint(), 4), 0xf0), bit.rshift(tvbuf(23, 1):uint(), 4))) ..
        string.char(bit.bor(bit.band(bit.lshift(tvbuf(23, 1):uint(), 4), 0xf0), bit.rshift(tvbuf(24, 1):uint(), 4)))
        )
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I really like the idea you came up with. But, I don't know if I am doing something wrong or what is it but... It returns 

`Harer ID : ` and nothing more. Do you have any suggestion on how should I try to modify my code? (I don't get any debugging errors)

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working for you; it works in my testing.  I'll propose an alternate solution ...